# Creating multiple layer HDFS folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

For creating `/user/SVLSTSLS/LostSales/sales-history-prep` HDFS folder one can create HDFS folders incrementally like:

```
bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/SVLSTSLS
bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/SVLSTSLS/LostSales
bash-4.1$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/SVLSTSLS/LostSales/sales-history-prep
```

Is there any way by which I can create final folder `sales-history-prep` as well as all intermediate folders (`SVLSTSLS` and `LostSales`), if not already present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for the `-p` flag.

If you use this flag, parent directories are also made if needed.
Try it yourself

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p  q/w/e/r
```

This should work, whilst the following will fail:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir  r/q/w/e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/SVLSTSLS/LostSales/sales-history-prep
```

From [the documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#mkdir):

> The -p option behavior is much like Unix mkdir -p, creating parent
>   directories along the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p <paths>
```

`-p` option will create whole directory structure regardless parent directories were created or not.

You can provide multiple path to create, within single command by separating them with whitespace. For example,

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /fld1/fld11/fld111 /fld1/fld11/fld112
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to create hdfs folders (as well the intermediate folders) in JAVA code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.FsPermission;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


Configuration hadoopConfiguration = new Configuration();
hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path("C:\\Xiang\\Softwares\\hadoop3.2\\hadoop-3.2.1\\etc\\hadoop\\core-site.xml"));



Path hdfs_P190415 = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9820/wimp/contract-snapshot/year=2019/month=4/day=15");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration)
fs.mkdirs(hdfs_P190415);
```

Then a folder (as well as the intermediate folders) will be created on the HDFS system. You can check under the terminal

```
hadoop fs -ls "/wimp/contract-snapshot/year=2019"
```

[image]

[image]

Before I run above code, the folder ~/month=4/day=15 does not exist. Now both the intermediate folder "~/month=4" and the final subfolder "~/month=4/day=15" are created.

The above JAVA code is tested on a standalone (windows) HDFS system, but should also work with multi clusters on a linux/production environment.